# How to access widget placement properties in kivy.animation

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to know how for the animation if the object collides with another object.

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
     anim = Animation(pos=(int(touch.x),int(touch.y)))
     anim.start(self.ids.play)
     if obja collide objb:
         anim.stop(self.ids.play)
```

Comment: I have never tried this, but I suspect you could use the `on_progress` events of `Animation` to check overlap at every move.

Comment: And what would the use of this event look like? The on_progress? how to use? help please.

Answer (score 0):

You use `bind` to bind events to methods. In your `on_touch_down` method:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
     anim = Animation(pos=(int(touch.x),int(touch.y)))
     anim.bind(on_progress=self.progress)
     anim.start(self.ids.play)
```

Then the `progress` method will get called for every increment of animation that gets applied to the animated widget:

```
def progress(self, anim, widget, progress):
    if widget.collide_widget(objb):
        anim.stop(widget)
```

Obviously, `objb` is undefined, but you can figure that out.

You will need to think about the sizes of your widgets, because (in some cases) the size may not be obvious, and the `collide_widget` method just compares bounding boxes.

Comment: thanks, my question was exactly how to link the event to a method.